# Number of Records Between two datetime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

It gives me this error when I run the script: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean. It is driving me crazy.

I get data from input box like this: 2017-12-14 06:42:10

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) as total FROM `purchase` where purchase_datetime BETWEEN str_to_date($date1, 'Y-m-d H:i:s') and str_to_date($date2, 'Y-m-d H:i:s')";
```

or

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) as total FROM `purchase` where purchase_datetime BETWEEN '$date1' and '$date2'";
```

or
Trying This:

```
$date1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date1);
$date2 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date2);
```

FULL CODE:

```
            <?php
            if (isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['date1']) && isset($_POST['date2'])) {
                $date1 = $_POST['date1'];
                $date2 = $_POST['date2'];

                $date1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date1);
                $date2 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date2);


                $sql = "SELECT count(*) as total FROM `purchase` where purchase_datetime BETWEEN '$date1' and '$date2'";
                $query_result = $conn->query($sql);
                $rows = $query_result->fetch_assoc();
                echo "Result is: " . $rows['total'] . " purchases";
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: Tip: use `$result = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);` to see the error in your SQL.

Comment: `It gives me this error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean. It is driving me crazy.` -> please show your full code

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh Full code

Answer (score 0):

The `date` function is to format today's date, not a given date. Use the `DateTime::format` function to format a given date. Try this:

```
$date1 = $date1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$date2 = $date2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM purchase WHERE purchase_datetime BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2';";
```

Alternatively, you can use the `date_format` alias function like this:

```
$date1 = date_format($date1, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
$date2 = date_format($date2, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM purchase WHERE purchase_datetime BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2';";
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure your format as:

```
$date1=$_POST['date1']//1496620800;
$date2=$_POST['date2']//1496707200;
$date1 = date('Y-m-d', $date1);//2017-06-05
$date2 = date('Y-m-d', $date2);//2017-06-06
```

purchase_datetime format:2017-xx-xx